# Is there a workaround in the nodemailer package for other services?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemailer

I noticed by looking at nodemailer [docs](https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/setup-smtp/well-known-services/) that they didn't support unoeruo mails as a service. Is there a workaround or do i need to use another package. And if i need to use another is there anyone you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

The "well know services" are just for your convenience. You can always create the SMTP Transport on your own, while using the [settings from unoeuro](https://www.unoeuro.com/en/support/faq/mail/606/)

Assuming you are using typescript, it would look like this. Just set user and pass to your credentials:

```
import * as Smtp from 'nodemailer';

const options = {
   host: "websmtp.unoeuro.com",
   port: 587,
   secure: true,
   auth: {
     user: "YOUR-LOGIN",
     pass: "YOUR-PASSWORD"
   };
};

const transport = Smtp.createTransport(options);
//do something with transport:
transport.sendMail({...});
```

Comment: Thank you but the host is actually asmtp.unoeuro.com.

Comment: Where did you get the host from? The unoeuro faq explicitly states *websmtp* and says it should be used for skripts. It also says that "This server can only be used by your scripts, from our web servers, and not by normal mail clients or from servers located elsewhere." In case it works with *asmtp*, good for you. Beware that some hosters might have restrictions in terms of the number of mails sent, that won't apply if you use *websmtp*. If in doubt, just ask your hoster directly.

Comment: It simply doesn't allow me to send mails with websmtp.. But asmtp works